# How to make a new field in an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

Sorry I have had to submit this question again because I have had hardly any views as it is an old post. I am desperate though for this to be answered. Please help me.

I have an array which will fetch rows from the database. But what I want to do is to create a new empty row in the table where if $row['StudentAnswer'] equals $row['AnswerContent'] then new field (lets say its called $row['StudentAnswerWeight']) = $row['Weight%'] else $row['StudentAnswerWeight'] = '0'.

For example: $row['Answercontent'] = Leeds (This is the correct answer for the question.) $row['StudentAnswer'] = Leeds (This is what the student has put for the answer.) The $row['weight%'] is the percentage of the mark for the correct answer. Lets say that the answer for the above example = 5% of the total marks. Now as the above example shows that the student's answer has matched the correct answer it means that in the new field which I want to create (lets call it ($row['StudentAnswerWeight']) to display the wieght% percentage of the answer which is 5%. If the studnet got the answer wrong by lets say the Student put in his/her answer 'Manchester'. The studentanswerweight should = 0% as that the answer is wrong. I hope you now understand what I want to acheive.

Can't we make a new $row['...']($row['StudentAnswerWeight' is what the new $row['...'] will be called) and use an if statement. If $row['AnswerContent'] = $row['StudentAnswer'] then $row['...'] = $row['Weight%'] else $row['...'] = '0'. I was thinking along those lines but I could not get it to work, I hope you guys can figure it out :)

Below is the array and the fields in the table in php code:

```
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th>Session ID</th>
  <th>Question Number</th>
  <th>Question</th>
  <th>Correct Answer</th>
  <th>StudentAnswer</th>
  <th>Correct Answer Weight</th>
  <th>Student Answer Weight</th>
  <th>Student ID</th>
  </tr>
  <?php

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "
  <tr>
  <td>{$row['SessionId']}</td>
  <td>{$row['QuestionNo']}</td>
  <td>{$row['QuestionContent']}</td>
  <td>{$row['AnswerContent']}</td>
  <td>{$row['StudentAnswer']} </td>
  <td>{$row['Weight%']}</td>
  <td>{$row['StudentAnswer'] = $row['AnswerContent']}</td> 
  <td>{$row['StudentId']}</td>
  </tr>";
    }
  ?>
```

Thank You

Comment: Does this not work? echo ($row['StudentAnswer'==$row['AnswerContent']) ? $row['Weight%'] : '0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before `echo`:

```
if ( $row['StudentAnswer'] == $row['AnswerContent'] ) {
  $row['StudentAnswerWeight'] = $row['Weight%'];
} else {
  $row['StudentAnswerWeight'] = '0';
}
```

And get rid of this `{$row['StudentAnswer'] = $row['AnswerContent']}`.

Comment: you mean replace, not get rid of right?  This answer should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `echo ($row['StudentAnswer']==$row['AnswerContent']) ? $row['Weight%'] : '0'`

in your example:

```
<?php

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "
  <tr>
  <td>{$row['SessionId']}</td>
  <td>{$row['QuestionNo']}</td>
  <td>{$row['QuestionContent']}</td>
  <td>{$row['AnswerContent']}</td>
  <td>{$row['StudentAnswer']} </td>
  <td>{$row['Weight%']}</td>
  <td>";
echo ($row['StudentAnswer']==$row['AnswerContent']) ? $row['Weight%'] : '0';
echo "</td><td>{$row['StudentId']}</td>
  </tr>";
    }
  ?>
```